# Multiple JFrame or JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

I'm developing an application with Swing and there is a situation that I couldn't decide to what to do. I need multiple pages but;

- Should I use multiple `JFrame` or `JDialog` or something else?
- What are the advantages of them? Is there specific way to choose?

Comment: I need multiple pages but; = CardLayout

Comment: You'll find this helpful: [The Use of Multiple JFrames Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `JDesktopPane` with `JInternalFrame`s. With that technique you can create as many windows as you need. A good place to start with this is here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html.

Comment: I was exactly checking, JDesktopPane with JInternalFrame. thank you for your attention.

Comment: FYI: The MDI paradigm has been deprecated for more years then I care to remember

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Ok, what is the recommended approach if multiple documents are needed? I used the java mdi a few month ago and was pleased about it.

Comment: @chris `CardLayout`, `JTabbedPane`, pretty much anything else :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer: i just loved (i promise to never use it again:) the way the user can create, arrange, resize, close the windows at runtime as needed.

Comment: @chris I spent the last 6 years trying to disassemble a MDI based application because (amongst other things), it's a monolithical pile of ... joy and happiness, but it was always the wrong choice for what the organisation was trying to do, just wish I had been there when they were making the decisions.  It's impossible to have any sort of application context for a single document and if one crashes, they all crash, then theirs the issues of memory within a shared context, blah, blah, blah :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer: ok, got it. Thx for the infos, was helpful for me and will be probably for others.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use multiple JTabbedPane in a JFrame which will make your work eassier.

see the link below:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html